# Capture Full Webview to Bitmap

Tags: android, cordova, webview, bitmap, native

I want to ask about webview :
I can't capture full page in webview. I can only capture the view that appears on the screen only, as I want to capture the full page. How to?

This is my webview :

```
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
                    }
                    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

                    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewLayout);
                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
                        }
                    });
                    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    webview.loadUrl("https://example.com");

                    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
```

and this is to convert into bitmap

```
            private void Print_BMP(){

                    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageViewPicture.getDrawingCache());
                    int nMode = 0;
                    int nPaperWidth = 384;
                    if(width_58mm.isChecked())
                        nPaperWidth = 384;
                    if(mBitmap != null)
                    {
                        byte[] data = PrintPicture.POS_PrintBMP(mBitmap, nPaperWidth, nMode);

                        SendDataByte(Command.ESC_Init);
                        SendDataByte(Command.LF);
                        SendDataByte(data);
                        SendDataByte(PrinterCommand.POS_Set_PrtAndFeedPaper(30));
                        SendDataByte(PrinterCommand.POS_Set_Cut(1));
                        SendDataByte(PrinterCommand.POS_Set_PrtInit());
                    }       
                }
```

and this is for keylistener

```
            private void KeyListenerInit() {

                    btnScanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
                    btnScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                    width_58mm = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.width_58mm);
                    width_58mm.setOnClickListener(this);

                    imageViewPicture = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewLayout);
                    imageViewPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture, scroll, capture, repeat as necessary.

Then assemble the individual images if you need to after that.

The add-in browser tools that provide this functionality appear to work in this same way.

Comment: Please anyone can help my problem :(